# How to wait for a popup to close in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, callback, popup

In jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 i'm using the new popup widget.

```
$('#my_popup').popup('close');
$('#my_popup').popup('open');
```

I obviously want to wait until the the popup closes completely before i open it again.
The close method does not provide a callback function option.

Comment: The methods for close and open should definitely have callback functions. I am aware that I can use the afterclose event, but I dont want the same action to kick off if the user quits the popup, and so I have to provide a check for that. 
There is nothing in the roadmap (http://jquerymobile.com/roadmap/) that indicates this will be fixed. Even the versjon 1.6 adoption of the dialog widget in jQueryUI wont fix the problem.
So, we'll just have to do with the somewhat cumbersome afterclose event workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the popupafterclose event, below is the snippet on how to do it.

For more information you can look at the [jQuery-Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/events.html)

```
$( "#my_popup" ).bind({
   popupafterclose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```